# Jenkins not compiling with .NET Core 3.1 version using MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I have an environment where Jenkins has installed locally and there are 4 visual studio projects inside the solution having all .NET Core 3.1 version. I installed the build tools for Visual Studio 2019 and MSBuild plugin for Jenkins. **I do not have full IDE installed for Visual Studio 2019.**

I also ran the "**dotnet --info**" where the jenkins is installed and here is the output:
[image]

After doing this step also I am not able to compile the project. Please see the error below:
[image: Error seen while building Jenkins]

I also tried setting the environment variables but it is not helping using the instruction in this page (https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2532). **Can someone please help and point me what I am doing wrong.**

**EDIT**

I restarted the server and now I am getting this error:
[image: Error after restart of the server]

Comment: How did you invoke a build?

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I have set the Global Configuration of Jenkins to this MSBuild Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin" and using this to do a manual build of the Visual Studio solution.

Comment: Did you try to invoke a [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) command directly?

Comment: I tried by opening a new CMD window where Jenkins is installed and it is working but when use MSBuild with Jenkins it is not working. Also I now restarted my server and I see a new error. It is able to download Nuget packages now but throwing the error --- "The runtime pack for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded. Try running a NuGet restore with the RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'"

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**I am just posting the solution what worked for me during that time. This was long time back and hence pasting images that I kept in my notes for future reference.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue:

"**The runtime pack for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded. Try running a NuGet restore with the RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64**'

When building a .NET Core 3.1 application (sln with multiple csproj files) using MSBuild in a Windows self-hosted runner in GitHub actions (I don't think the CI tooling has nothing to do with the problem as I could reproduce it on my own Windows machine).

The way I managed to solve it was by adding the following **RuntimeIdentifiers** section to the csproj files:

```html
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Also, before building the project with MSBuild (I had to use MSBuild because I was building an MSI and couldn't use dotnet to build) I would do a dotnet restore with the -r switch and win-x64 as the value:

```
dotnet restore -r win-x64
```